# Error while compiling APK file: EAS BUILD

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm using EXPO CLI to develop app and to create test-build, i run this command:
`eas build -p android --profile preview`
and it stops after few minutes with this/or similar message:

`Compressing project files Error: Cannot copy a socket file: /Users/mac/Library/Group  Containers/BJ4HAAB9B3.ZoomClient3rd/s.zzhost`
It is always issue with compressing files stage.
How to solve it?

I tried change directory and other similar command.
Is it possible that mistake is in app?